# Some files measurement in the IMA (Integrity Measurement Architecture) does not correspond to the result generated by sha1sum command

Tags: 16.04, security, tpm

I am using the sha1sum command to check the hash of some files and compare with the measurements stored in the IMA. However, I identified some files whose measurement in the IMA does not correspond to the result generated by SHA1. When I restart the VM the measurements of these files do not change, but they are always different. Does anyone know why this happens?

**sha1 from IMA:**

```
10 e0e5b82e2ed305ffc0a188a281b4ca8c79ea3de1 ima-ng sha1:0da0a24d06523e494b40f5949720ad04cc6bb5bc /lib/modules/4.4.0-201-generic/modules.softdep 

10 5fc7b38c2b675c5c2f6c1408beac837070ce2c33 ima-ng sha1:ed84d077b0e23007c21fae313c59276e1cac958e /lib/modules/4.4.0-201-generic/modules.dep.bin 

10 2f320ddb54089f394bbc308a2b4c893327adb370 ima-ng sha1:ea87b5b48026af8cf8a7e12901ebf42e6f327733 /lib/modules/4.4.0-201-generic/modules.alias.bin 

10 9bb3e48340449e825b6f28eee3122ae82e790b17 ima-ng sha1:f1f5b3065fa88d78e9a0bf1df0eca2b88e7b1f29 /lib/modules/4.4.0-201-generic/modules.symbols.bin

10 d57dfb1ebcd8807b75f187266ae526f27b8317b8 ima-ng sha1:bd6e6f52845c0767c4bf045fd188e5b7faf4a3f1 /lib/modules/4.4.0-201-generic/modules.dep
```

**and sha1 generated by the sha1sum command:**

```
72de57d6697c1fb1ec201f2b8a09f4cfdc6c37e5  /lib/modules/4.4.0-201-generic/modules.softdep 

258514cdb6d47ca853c525798186682bcd4af6b1  /lib/modules/4.4.0-201-generic/modules.dep.bin  

6f58819412d7ecb844872576e293fdd2b37873bf  /lib/modules/4.4.0-201-generic/modules.alias.bin 

6f6ed47c5bcb69ec301502476e9d4c1ee890b7c7  /lib/modules/4.4.0-201-generic/modules.symbols.bin                                               

7f4ed654edec5a139b5810ede1773fc609f4de6d  /lib/modules/4.4.0-201-generic/modules.dep
```